# SAP UI5 Create view with parameters

Tags: sapui5

I have a view which I call in few other views with `xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"` and it's component `XMLView` like that:

```
<mvc:XMLView viewName="myViewPatch"
   height="100%" id="myId" app:myProp="myProp" />
```

I want to access `myProp` in `myViewPatch.controller` but I think it's not possible that way because `myProp` is assigned to the `mvc:XMLView` not to the `View` itself. Is there any way to fake/create some kind of constructor? P.S. I am not able to use fragment and use different controllers.

Comment: Fragment should be the way to go. What's the problem you face there ?